# Is it possible to a root of a Gaussian integer be a Hurwitz quaternion?

Tags: roots, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to solve the equation
$$
E(x)=\frac{(1+ix)^{1/2}-(1-ix)^{1/2}}{(1+ix)^{1/2}+(1-ix)^{1/2}} \mod p,
$$

where $p$ is a prime and $1+ix$ is a Gaussian integer over $p$. For some values of $x$, there is no solution for the $\sqrt{1+ix}$ in the complex field, i.e., is a quadratic nonresidue. I'm just an engineer student, my knowledge in the area is not great. There is a possibility that the solution is in an extension field like the Hurwitz quaternion?

Comment: What does “Gaussian integer over $p$“ mean?

Comment: There is always a complex value for $\sqrt{1+ix}$ over the complex field.

Comment: It is also unclear what is meant by your equation - the expression on the right has to be in some ring in order to make $\mod p$ mean anything, but you haven’t specified the ring. And even if the right side could be made to mean something, this simply seems to define $E(x),$ so it is not clear what it means to “solve” this equation.

Comment: Rationalizing the denominator by multiplying  numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1+xi}-\sqrt{1-xi}$ you get:

$$\frac{\left(\sqrt{1+xi}-\sqrt{1-xi}\right)^2}{2xi}=\frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}{x}i ,$$ at least for $x\neq0.$

Comment: Hello Thomas, sorry for not explain well my problem. I'm working with Gaussian integer over GF(p), or a finite field under p. This is a problem like a quadratic residue on number theory, where there is no solution to $x^2=a \mod p$. I wondering if the quaternions is a extension field of the complex numbers and if I can find my solution in the quaternions for quadratic nonresidues.

Comment: The complex numbers have nothing to do with finite fields. First, stop using “complex numbers” to discuss finite fields.  There is not always an $i$ in $\mathbb F_p,$ and there is no single meaning to $\sqrt{\cdot},$ but we can always define $E:\mathbb F_p\to\mathbb F_{p^2},$ using my trick above. $E(x)\in\mathbb F_p$ only if $x=0$ or $-1$and $1+x^2$ are quadratic residue modulo $p.$

Comment: But quaternions generally don’t have a useful generalization in finite fields, for the basic reason that there are no finite non-commutative fields, so having $ij=-ji $ means any finite ring corresponding to quaternions won’t even be an integral domain.

Comment: Also, “Gaussian integers over $\mathbb F_p$” doesn’t mean anything.

Comment: Sorry about the complex numbers, what I mean was a Gaussian integer that can be isomorphic with some $\mathbf{F}_{q^2}$. But I understand what you mean, I guess I can't solve the way I want. And about $\sqrt{x}$, the meaning is like finding a to solve $a^2\equiv x \mod p$ and you have something similar to a square root.

Comment: You should edit your question to say what you mean. What do you mean by “solve,” for example?

Answer (score 2):

As @ThomasAndrews notes, your terminology is not quite standard, and gets tangled up with some mathematical issues, but perhaps I can guess what you are wanting.

Let $\mathbb F_q$ denote the finite field with $q$ elements. It is standard that there exists such a thing exactly for $q$ a power of a prime, and that then there is a unique ("up to isomorphism") such thing.

For $p$ a prime, $\mathbb F_p$ contains a $\sqrt{-1}$ if and only if $p=1\mod 4$ (or $p=2$, which is a degenerate case). So, for $p=3\mod 4$, adjoining a $\sqrt{-1}$ to $\mathbb F_p$ gives a strictly larger field $\mathbb F_{p^2}$. We could still call the $\sqrt{-1}$ "$i$", if we want.

I suspect that this is your set-up and you want to *simplify* the expression you wrote. So, yes, there is the subordinate question: for which $x\in \mathbb F_p$ is there a $\sqrt{1+ix}$ in $\mathbb F_{p^2}$ (for example).

An auxiliary fact (also standard), that may be useful to you, is that $x^2+1=y^2$ has a solution $(x,y)$ in $\mathbb F_p$, for every $p\not=2$. But, still, not every $x^2+1$ is a square in $\mathbb F_p$. Because of the uniqueness of $\mathbb F_{p^2}$, every $x^2+1$ *is* a square in that quadratic extension.

Some simplification can be done by "rationalizing the denominator", just as in more mundane algebra situations.

But/and if you can clarify what you're needing/wanting, more pointed answers could be given. :)

(As @ThomasAndrews already noted, there *are* no finite division algebra ("quaternions") except fields. But/and the theory of finite fields is simple and "happy" enough that many questions can be answered...)

Answer (score 1):

What you propose is possible to do. Suppose $\,p\,$ is an odd prime. Let
$$ E(x):=\frac{(1+ix)^{1/2}-(1-ix)^{1/2}}{(1+ix)^{1/2}+(1-ix)^{1/2}} \pmod p. $$
First, simplify the quotient to get (if $\,x\ne 0$ otherwise $E(0)=0$)
$$ E(x) = i \frac{\sqrt{1+x^2}-1}x \pmod p. $$
Here we understand $\,i\,$ to mean a square root of $\,-1\pmod p\,$ if $\,p-1\,$ is a quadratic residue, or else it exists in an extension field. Again, the same problem arises for $\,\sqrt{1+x^2}\,$ if $\,1+x^2\,$ is not
a quadratic residue and so use an extension field. Thus, we may need to use two extension fields to make sense of $\,E(x).\,$ Note that $\,E(-x)=-E(x)\,$
for all $\,x.\,$

For example, let $\,p=3.\,$ Define $\,i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{2}\,$ in an extension
field of $\,\mathbb F_3.\,$ We already know $\,E(0)=0.\,$ Now $\,E(1)=2+2i\,$ and
$\,E(2)=1+i.\,$

Another example, let $\,p=5.\,$ Here $\,-1=2^2=3^2\pmod 5\,$ thus $\,i=2.\,$
Now we need $\,r:=\sqrt{2}\,$ in an extension field of $\,\mathbb F_5\,$
and thus,
$$E(0)=0,\; E(1)=3+2r,\; E(2)=4,\; E(3)=1,\; E(4)=2+3r. $$